# Serialization: good or bad in a multi-thread environment to maintain a cache?

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization

Which is a better approach:

- Using serialization to create a cache, or
- Simply writing objects in the form of string arrays to a file using delimiters?

Recently I was told that serialization creates a different thread to process, and should not be used in a multi-threaded environment/application with timing constraints where you need faster processing and less interruption!

So is it true that serialization is inefficient in a big multi-threaded java project ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with serialization.  Can be used in multi-threaded environments without any worries

Comment: "simply writing objects values in the form of string arrays to a file using delimiters" -- You just described a very simple form of serialization. Java Serialization is not done on a different thread. Whether you should use it or not depends on many factors that you haven't given and that would probably be too long and opinionated for a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Any disk I/O will block the thread that is performing it. If performance is paramount think of asynchronous(fire-and-forget) solutions or in-memory cache. Also don't be doing premature optimization sometimes its known as "root of all evils"

Comment: What you were told about serialization creating another thread is complete and utter BS.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization does not take a place on a different thread. While java serializes the object, if another thread is trying to modify the same object, you may run into a consistency issues as the state of the object is being changed while serialization is taking place. 
You could run in to the same issue with your own implementation. To answer the question "If the serialization to build your cache is efficient", I would suggest you to look at the cache implementations (some good open source like hazlecast or ehcache).

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it's not true that serialization in inefficient in a multi-threaded Java project.

Speaking of standard Java serialization, it happens inside the same thread that calls serialization, and it can be used in a mulch-threaded environment.  Using  locks is needed while serializing an object that is accessible for write by multiple threads. Caches like [Cacheonix](https://github.com/cacheonix/cacheonix-core) (I'm a committer) do their part when in comes to making sure internal data structures are thread-safe.

At the same time, serializing an arbitrary Java object that was not designed with caching in mind can be time-consuming. A simple way to design for caching is to make sure, if possible, that your keys and values have only simple fields like ints and Strings, and ideally immutable. This way a cache can be hinted (in Cacheonix it is implementing Immutable interface) that an object can be passed by reference thus allowing the cache to avoid serialization all together by passing the objects by reference.

Hope this helps.